# foreach loop with Session in C# using MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, foreach

I'm creating a shopping cart for my project in C# using MVC 4.
I stored 3 values: name, price and description as an array in a session.
When I try to call the Session for a foreach loop, it says
"foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"
What would I have to change?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Courses.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ANON_Capstone.Models.Course>

@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
@section featured
{
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <h2 class="text-center">Please Login or Create an Account to make a Purchase!</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
}
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <h2><strong>Courses</strong></h2><br />
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-s-8 col-lg-4">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ShoppingCart", "Home"))
            {
                <img src="~/Images/party.gif" style="width: 175px" class="img-responsive" />
                <h2>@item.className</h2>
                <p>$@item.classPrice -- @item.maxStudent spots left! </p>
                <input type="text" name="product" value="@item.className" hidden="hidden" />
                <input type="text" name="totalPrice" value="@item.classPrice" hidden="hidden"  />
                <input type="text" name="custom" value="@item.ClassID" hidden="hidden" />
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Add to Shopping Cart" />
                }
            }
            <br />
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ANON_Capstone.Models;

namespace ANON_Capstone.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Courses()
    {

        return View(db.Courses.ToList());

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShoppingCart()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ShoppingCart(string className, string classPrice, string classDesc)
    {
        String[] cart = { className, classPrice, classDesc };
        Session["Cart"] = cart;
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

ShoppingCart.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ShoppingCart";
}

<h2>ShoppingCart</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateCommand", "PayPal"))
{
var cart = Session["Cart"];
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <h2><strong>Courses</strong></h2><br />
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-s-8 col-lg-4">
        @foreach (var item in cart)
        {
            <img src="~/Images/party.gif" style="width: 175px" class="img-responsive" />
            <h2>@item.className</h2>
            <input type="text" name="product" value="@item.className" hidden="hidden" />
            <input type="text" name="totalPrice" value="@item.classPrice" hidden="hidden"  />
            <input type="text" name="custom" value="@item.ClassID" hidden="hidden" />
        }
        <br />
        </div>

    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Check Out with Paypal" />

</div>
}
```

Comment: How are you storing cart items in the session in the first place? Is it a list? The error is pretty self explanatory.. you're pulling an `object` out of the Session.. `object` isn't `IEnumerable`..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Hi Simon, I am passing the variables from a model through a controller. The controller takes 3 parameters which are name, price, and desc. I then make a string array of the three objects and store it into Session.

Comment: If it is a string array.. then you need to cast it back out as one. I'll show you in an answer.

Comment: What you have is one cart items, but in view you are trying to access it as a collection orders.

Comment: @evhen14 what would I have to do in order to access it as a collection? do I have to cast the session object as collection? or create multiple session?

Comment: @Young-kyuQHan see my answer below. But it's based on some assumptions about your db object. One of them is that it has a list of orders.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a collection of order items in your cart.

To achieve that do something like

```
public ActionResult ShoppingCart(string className, string classPrice, string classDesc)
{        
    Session["Cart"] = db.Orders.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Then use

```
var cart = Session["Cart"] as IEnumerable<Order>;
```

in your View to access those items

Comment: Hi, I tried your method and it worked, but now it appears that I can't retrieve the name, price or the description.

Comment: Are you getting some sort or error? This may end up being an unrelated issue.

Comment: String[] cart = { className, classPrice, classDesc }; This will not create what you want. It just represents one order in terms of strings. But you need a collection of objects with properties

Comment: @evhen14 Sorry, I'm pretty bad with programming and programming terms. What do you mean collection of objects with properties?

Comment: @Young-kyuQHan objects that have properties on them

Comment: @evhen14 Thank you for the clarification. the model that I'm using is Courses. So, I made the changes and changed Order to Courses. When I try to make cart = Session["Cart"] as IEnumerable<Courses>;, it says the type or namespace cannot be found.

Comment: @evhen14 Sorry about all the confusion. I think I finally got what you were saying. If I use your method, wouldn't it return all the courses instead of returning just the selected courses?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the code a specific type to use. By default all session variables are objects. Because you are using var, the compiler is looking at the session variable and, since no cast is done, doesn't know what type to use, so it defaults to a single object. Based on what I see it looks like you have a class such as:

```
public class CartItem
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public money ClassPrice { get; set; }
    public int ClassID { get; set; }
}
```

Where you store CartItem[] in session. In this case, to loop over the items you need to cast the item to CartItem[] when you get it out of session with:

```
var cart = Session["Cart"] as IEnumerable<CartItem>;
```

Depending on it's location you may need to include a using statement in your view to reference the namespace holding CartItem.

Comment: arrays support IEnumerable<>. So that should be Session["Cart"] as IEnumerable<CartItem>;

Comment: @evhen14 you're right. I noticed it in a later answer after I posted this. You can easily use the IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're storing the cart items as a string array.. you need to cast them back out as one:

```
var cart = Session["Cart"] as string[];
```

You can then use it in your `foreach`, because arrays are enumerable.

However, your code contains things like `@item.ClassID`.. this makes me assume that the cart items aren't actually a string array.. but a list of objects.

Comment: I might have messed up with storing it in the Session. I tried to store it without making it a string array the first time and it gave me an error. So I made the three objects go into an array first, and then made the Session.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make this strongly typed with the CartItem and pass an

```
    List<CartItem>
```

either a strongly typed model with:

```
return View(new List<CartItem> { item1, item2});
```

and have your view use a model List.

Either this or use the the ViewBag and pass down this strongly typed list.

Once in the view you can define a new variable:

Server:

```
 ViewBag.Items = new List<CartItem> { item1, item2 };
```

Client:

```
 List<CartItem> items = ViewBag.Items as List<CartItem>
```